# Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath' to expected argument type 'NSIndexPath'

Tags: ios, swift, nsindexpath

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath' to expected argument type 'NSIndexPath'

Error is on `self.collectionView?.moveItemAtIndexPath(obj[0] as! NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: obj[1] as! NSIndexPath) line`

```
if let changes = self.objectChanges{
    self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
        for change in changes as NSArray as! [NSDictionary] {
            change.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock { (keyObject:AnyObject!, obj:AnyObject!, stop) -> Void in
                let key = keyObject as! NSNumber
                let type = NSFetchedResultsChangeType(rawValue: key.unsignedLongValue)!
                switch (type)
                {
                    case .Insert:
                        self.collectionView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(obj as! ([NSIndexPath]))
                    case .Delete:
                        self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(obj as! ([NSIndexPath]))
                    case .Update:
                        self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(obj as! ([NSIndexPath]))
                    case .Move:
                        self.collectionView?.moveItemAtIndexPath(obj[0] as! NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: obj[1] as! NSIndexPath)
                    default:
                        break
                }
            }
        }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You really need to stop using the wrong tags on all of your questions.

Comment: could you print(obj) in the .Move case and post the output

Comment: Error messages like that from Swift are generally red herrings, and are caused by some other syntax error. I'm confused by `for change in changes as NSArray as! [NSDictionary]` - what happens if you bracket it to assure the casts are happening as you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply subscript to `obj` which is `AnyObject` not `Array`.
You should cast `obj` to `[NSIndexPath]`:

```
if let obj = obj as? [NSIndexPath] {
    switch (type) {
        case .Insert:
            self.collectionView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(obj)
        case .Delete:
            self.collectionView?.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(obj)
        case .Update:
            self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(obj)
        case .Move:
            self.collectionView?.moveItemAtIndexPath(obj[0], toIndexPath: obj[1])
        default:
            break
    }
}
```